# Validation is not working for these and unable to write something in the forum

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

**I am using this form from the react bootstrap. But when i am trying to validate it is not working. Can some one please help here and thanks in adavance.**

but when i am trying to validate the username, email and phone, I am unable to do it also unable to write something in the forum, can some one please help me where i made exact error

```
  import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Col, Form, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';

const AddressValidation = () => {
  const initialValues = { username: "", email: "", password: "" };
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});
  const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
    setIsSubmit(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(formErrors);
    if (Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
      console.log(formValues);
    }
  }, [formErrors]);
  const validate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    const regex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/i;
    if (!values.username) {
      errors.username = "Username is required!";
    }
    if (!values.email) {
      errors.email = "Email is required!";
    } else if (!regex.test(values.email)) {
      errors.email = "This is not a valid email format!";
    }
    if (!values.username) {
      errors.username= "usernameis required";
    } else if (values.username.length < 4) {
      errors.username= "username must be more than 4 characters and combination of 3 letters";
    } else if (values.username.length > 10) {
      errors.username= "username cannot exceed more than 10 characters";
    }
    return errors;
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
     <pre>{JSON.stringify(formValues, undefined, 2)}</pre>
     <Form onSubmit = { handleSubmit }>
            <h1> Payment Validation  Form</h1>
            <Row className="mb-3">

                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridUsername">
                <Form.Label>User Name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter User Name"  value={ formValues.username}
                    onChange = {handleChange}/>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridEmail">
                <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" value={ formValues.email} 
                     onChange = {handleChange} />
                </Form.Group>
               
             <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPhone">
                <Form.Label>phonenumber</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="number" placeholder="Enter email" value={ formValues.phonenumber} 
                     onChange = {handleChange} />
                </Form.Group>

                
            </Row>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAddress1">
                <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control placeholder="1234 Main St" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAddress2">
                <Form.Label>Address 2</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Row className="mb-3">
                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
                <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridState">
                <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
                <Form.Select defaultValue="Choose...">
                    <option>Choose...</option>
                    <option>Stockholm</option>
                    <option>Mälmo</option>
                </Form.Select>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridZip">
                <Form.Label>Zip</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control />
                </Form.Group>
            </Row>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" id="formGridCheckbox">
                <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                Submit
            </Button>
     </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddressValidation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the *name* property to your inputs. Otherweise you get an empty name property from *event.target*:

```
<Form.Control
  name="username"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Enter User Name"
  value={formValues.username}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Your validation seems to work. When I try to submit, I can read the error messages in console:

```
{username: 'usernameis required', email: 'Email is required!'}
```

Comment: yes, that true. What you said is right, I identified after posted here and I am sorry for that. I copied some code in sandbox, I am trying validate the email and mobile number for that form, can you please help me?

Comment: validation is very different. HOW do you want to validate them? Please adjust the title and text in the initial post. Or accept my answer, close this one and create another question.

Comment: Initially i am trying to validate the email and phone number. But raising some issues and later i am changing some other thing and removed phone number but i have to validate email , username and phone number. But what problem is raising here is username is not assigning to username variable in the form and it should validate

Comment: it doesn't help...WHAT issues are raised? What kind of things did you change later? Please provide some code

Comment: I updated the link you share the sandbox. Is that fine or else here i should update?

Comment: please create your own. I can't find any changes im my sandbox. You didn't answer my questions though. And please update the title and text of initial post.

Comment: I try to wrote something in the field but it couldnt works for me, could you please help me?

Comment: In which field? What didn't work?

Comment: Please stop "spam". Give me a moment, I'm on it.

Comment: Please look into the edit of my post

Comment: sorry, I missed one more once i click on submit it should send response in JSON Format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243745/discussion-between-igor-gonak-and-sruthi).